# Checking if an array has at least 3 elements

Tags: arrays, riscv

I'm not sure how to approach this but put simply, a part of my homework states that I need to check if an array has at least 3 stored integer values and display an error message if it has less. The other part is getting the sum of all values in the array and show the output in the console.

I'm using RARS and the array is already declared in .data along with its values.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a notion of length, which can be in bytes, or in element count, but unlike Java and C#, there is no standardized way to represent this notion of length in assembly language or in C code.

Sometimes the length is represented in the program by a constant.

Sometimes the length is represented in the program by a variable, more or less directly as a count of elements (though a program variable could also be an index referring to the last element, in which case that count is that variable + 1).

Sometimes the length is represented in the program by an end pointer — a pointer one element past the last, and also the place to store the next element, if one comes, when growing the array in place is possible.

Sometimes the length is encoded as a special element value, a sentinel or terminator, and to find the length one traverses forwards until that element is found — there must be sufficient storage to hold the real elements and the sentinel as well but it not considered an element of the array.

C-style strings are arrays of character, nul-terminated, so use the special character `nul` aka `\0' or just 0 as the terminator.

We can also pair a length value with a pointer value to compose a higher level notion of array with length into an object or structure.

This is not necessarily a complete list, since programmers can do as they like.  (Other schemes are possible, such as storing the length at the beginning of the array, or in front of the array, i.e. at position -1 in the array).

A function taking an array as a parameter will often also take another parameter that is the length, but in the case of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` we see the length being passed as the first parameter and the array as the second..

It would be a logic error for a program to have an array whose length is unknown and not computable.

You will need to determine the method for representing the length, and then compare the length with your constant 3 as required.

For example, if the method is an end pointer, then you can subtract: end pointer - beginning pointer (the array base, or address of first element), and then divide that result by the array's element size, which will yield a count of the number of elements.

Comment: Thank you for the answering. In implementing the end pointer method, how do you find it without explicitly defining the position of the last element of the array?

Comment: Let's imagine you have space for 20 numbers, and ask the user to enter up to 20 numbers, say, entering maybe 0 when they're done.  You would start the end pointer at the beginning and each time the user enters a valid value, store it where the end pointer points, and advance the pointer to the next element.  In this manner, when you're done taking user input, you've captured all the items in the array and can compute how many there are, if you want a count, by the formula I provided above.

Comment: Otherwise, with just a bit more work inside the loop you can create a 2nd variable, a counter, initialize to 0 and and increment it by 1 each time the input loop stores, while also using the end pointer.  Then that counter holds the number of elements the user entered into the array.  And yet still you could forgo an end pointer and do array indexing given the counter.

Comment: Be aware that all of this applies equally well to both assembly language, and C, so you don't actually have to think in assembly language, as you can reference tutorials in C on pointers & arrays.

Comment: C has pointers, just like assembly -- the only difference in C is that since C knows the size of what the pointer is pointing to, so C, for example, will automatically divide by the size of the element (on subtraction, and multiply/scale by that size on addition), whereas in assembly you have to do that yourself.